# How to create overlapping UI using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I just started with Jetpack compose and i need help in creating this type of UI.
[wireframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfIhA.png)

I currently tried using a Box layout with two another Two Box layout as the contents, one for the rectangle part and the other one for the circular part. Is there a better way to achieve this.

```
package dev.hayohtee.practice

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.border
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.CircleShape
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.RectangleShape
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import dev.hayohtee.practice.ui.theme.PracticeTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            PracticeTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    MainScreen()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    Column {
        DemoLayout(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(250.dp)
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun DemoLayout(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Box(modifier = modifier) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .matchParentSize()
                .padding(top = 10.dp, start = 10.dp, end = 10.dp, bottom = 50.dp)
                .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                .border(2.dp, Color.Black, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
        )
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(100.dp)
                .clip(shape = CircleShape)
                .border(4.dp, Color.Black, CircleShape)
                .background(Color.White)
                .align(alignment = Alignment.BottomEnd)
        )
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    PracticeTheme {
        MainScreen()
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble with moving the box layout contents (Using offset or padding) after using the alignment modifier. Is there a better way to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

```
@Composable
fun DemoLayout(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
Box(modifier = modifier) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .matchParentSize()
            .padding(top = 10.dp, start = 10.dp, end = 10.dp, bottom = 50.dp)
            .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
            .border(2.dp, Color.Black, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
    )
    Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 10.dp)
        .align(alignment = Alignment.BottomEnd)
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(100.dp)
                .clip(shape = CircleShape)
                .border(4.dp, Color.Black, CircleShape)
                .background(Color.White)
                .align(alignment = Alignment.BottomEnd)
        )
     }
 }
}
```